# How to build report using Ipython notebook?

Tags: python, ipython

I use python with the editor spyder and the Ipython shell. 
I know that should be possible to build quick report (like the matlab publish function) but I can not find any guide or example on the web.

Can anyone help me to start?

Comment: Have you tried IPython Notebook?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking. Do you use the IPython notebook or spyder? The IPython notebook runs in the browser and produces .ipynb files while spyder produces .py files

Comment: The point is that I am very confused, I believed that the Ipyhton notebook was a function of Ipython shell. I can not find any example of Ipython notebook.

Comment: The the link to the examples of Ipython notebook does not work https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tree/master/examples/notebooks#a-collection-of-notebooks-for-using-ipython-effectively   can you suggest me any tutorial?

Comment: that was just a bug in nbviewer - those links work now.